# Python html parsing. (xpath works in browser, doesn't work in Python)

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to scrape a saved facebook page. I need to find posts with xpath (or in other way, but preferably xpath).
So I open that saved file in BROWSER:
and try my xpath expression. It works perfectly.

expression: //div[starts-with(@id,"mall_post_")]

[image]

but when I do the same in Python (Python3.4 or Python3.6) it finds NOTHING.
Here is the code:

```
import lxml.html as html    
with open('page03.html', 'rb') as htmlfile:
    page = htmlfile.read()

    res = html.fromstring(page)
    print(res)

    posts = res.xpath(u'//div[starts-with(@id,"mall_post_")]')
    print(posts)
```

[image]
Even if I try just to find all div's with id's (//div[@id]/@id) - it doesn't see half of the div's (with id) present in the document.

The saved html file is big - over 800 Kb, so I can't post it here, but I'll give a link to it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tz7kp695syk8jow/page04.html?dl=0

Please help to make it working, or maybe you know some other way to scrape these posts which support scraping/parsing for multiple parameters(author, text, comments, etc).

Comment: The `html` module doesn't have a `fromstring` method. Do you use an external library?

Comment: @MichaelButscher no, I guess not. The only import I'm using is import lxml.html as html

Comment: lxml is an external library

Comment: Posts are dynamic - there are no such content in initial page source, so you cannot scrape it in this way. You need a tool like Selenium to be able to handle content generated by JavaScript

Comment: @Andersson, to my regret - Selenium is not an option. What do you mean by dynamic? My file saved on the HDD is dynamic? This file opened in browser is xpath parsible. But opened in Python - not (well, it is parsed, but in a different way than in browser). So I need a help how to parse it in Python THE SAME WAY it is parsed in browser. Do you have any ideas? (P.S. The question is about parsing file on the HDD, not a page in the internet.)

Comment: @MichaelButscher, ok, it is external (I didn't know it). Does it helps us in any way?

Comment: @UserNew You should add the tag lxml to your question so people used to this library know that they should look at this question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, tag added.

Comment: @UserNew To answer the question you asked Andersson: The HTML page content in memory can be modified by JavaScript code executed in browser so that it doesn't match the initial code from file anymore (this is meant with "dynamic" here). Try to switch off JavaScript in your browser, open the page again and if your XPath expression works in browser yet, there is a chance that it can work in lxml as well.